# Rails first_or_initialize: do we need to index on db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

If we use first_or_initialize/first_or_create to build an object in rails (with all the attributes), do we need to index on all the attributes in the db to boost the performance?

Comment: It's going to look the first row up by the ID, so you might want to index on that. The rest are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need or want an index on all the attributes - in fact too many indexes will slow down your application since the database has to redo all the indexes when you insert/update.

Instead you want indexes on key attributes like `id` which are commonly used in queries.

If you want to use find or create and make sure the query is performant you can do it like this:

```
@user = User.create_with(user_params)
            .first_or_create(user_params[:email])
```

In this example you want an index on the `users.email` column.

And as @Andrew Piliser has pointed out if you pass an id it will only use the `id` column to find if the record exists.